# Removing/Resetting all bounds/markers from searchBar function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a searchBar function that I found on the GoogleMaps documentation which works like a charm for it's purpose, however the reason I'm using it is because I want users to be able to capture that GoogleMap as an image (Which I know how to do using HTML2Canvas)

The issue I'm having is that when I use the SearchBar function for some reason it seems to make the bounds "stick" to the bounds that were applied when the SearchBar is used, so when I try and render the canvas of the Google Map is viewport of the render stays the same as when the SearchBox was used, but the actual rendered image is in the location relative to the SearchBox viewport (You can see what I mean in the images below).

Image after SearchBar use:

[image]

Image when rendered near SearchBar viewport (this image was rendered when I was NW of the marker for the PostCode, the bottom-right corner of the area with an image in was the bottom-right of the visible area when starting the render):

[image]

As you can see above, the actual viewport of the image is the same in each. This leads me to believe that there is some form of issue with the bounds set in the SearchBox code shown below:

JavaScript:

```
var map;
var markers = [];
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: 54.559322, lng: -4.174804},
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        panControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: true
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var input = (document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

        markers = [];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
            var image = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            markers.push(marker);

            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });

}
```

What I think needs to be done is to remove/reset the bound information set in the SearchBox function when I run the render, but any information you can provide will be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Chris

Comment: Which version of html2canvas are you using?